# Where can i find the actor model for ROS Indigo and Gazebo2.2 version?

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want use face_detector package.  To use this package in simulation, i need to create the faces or actors in the gazebo simulator.
Can anyone please help where can i find the actor models for ROS indigo with Gazebo2.2 version.

Or is there any better way to detect and track the faces using face_detector without actor models?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236266/where-can-i-find-the-actor-model-for-ros-indigo-and-gazebo2.2-version?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is only supported after gazebo 8.

---

Originally posted by [onlytailei](https://answers.ros.org/users/25561/onlytailei/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0